# Cómo generar APK mediante Python-Kivy en windows?

Tags: python, kivy

sé que con buildozer puedo generar las apk, pero sólo corre en windows..
Existe algún otro paquete para armar el apk?

Comment: no entiendo, para qué sistema operativo necesitas esto?

Comment: Necesito para Windows

Comment: entonces porqué no buildozer? si corre en windows...

Comment: Sí? En la documentación oficial dice que no y en ningún lado ví como hacerlo funcionar en windows...

Comment: Anunque *Kivy* está disponible en *Windows*, *Buildozer* sólo se desarrolla para *Linux*. En *Windows* tu única opción sería utilizar el *subsistema de Windows para Linux* o una *Máquina virtual con Linux*.